# JIRA issue with "done" tasks

Tags: jira, scrum

Perhaps it is more psychological than programming question:

We use JIRA with Greenhopper in our work, so when I receive new tasks I see them at the Agile Board for current sprint. For every sprint I have a LOT of tasks, after I have fixed, for example five of them I set their state as *need test* and these tasks go to tester (he has not only my tasks to test as usual). If these tasks are tested and all is ok they *closed* by tester. The problem is - that I could not see how many tasks I have done. When they are *closed* they disappear from my *Agile* board and I see only new tasks there... Imagine - yesterday you have completed five tasks for current sprint, but today chief adds ten more tasks in this current sprint for you.

So: Number_Of_Tasks - 5 + 10 = Number_Of_Tasks + 5.

And thus the Agile Board has no visual progress for me - it grows in size. This is very demotivating

In short: How could I view my *done* tasks?

Comment: Need Test by all testers perhaps.. but "need test" not always means "done"

Comment: Can't you add the corresponding criteria to that Jira query as well?

Comment: perhaps I do. Thank you for that idea). Why you do not write this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Jira query as a filter. The query itself would look like this:

```
status WAS "Need Test" BY currentUser() AND status = Closed
```

... yes, quite like SQL. ) Here's the [official documentation link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching).

Answer (score 2):

You probably have the "Hide Done Issues" button ticked.

- Go to Agile > Task (Greenhopper Agile plugin needed)
- Above your Task board.  One is "Hide Done Issues". Click/Unclick that.

Your Done issues will now be displayed.

> Imagine - yesterday you have completed five tasks for current sprint, but today chief adds ten more tasks in this current sprint for you.

As for this, your chief needs coaching.  If you are doing SCRUM, then the "chief" (whoever that is) should not add extra work to your sprint.  If you finish your tasks early, you should pick some off a teamate who might have run into trouble, or you can test his stuff.  The point is to achieve the goals you (the team) have set for yourselves.  If everybody is done, then the sprint finishes early.  Good for you!

You can finish and replan the next sprint or teamates should pick off stuff from the backlog themselves.

The danger of a "chief" assigning you stuff is that these micro-managers may not have a detailed understanding of what has been done, what is to be done and what is un-tested and might be reopened by a tester.